# different event each clicking(tap) button in jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I make the button that have different class events on first and second tap in mobile ?

This is the html for button.

```
<a href="#" class="icon-white">click</a>
```

The button default class is **"icon-white".**

1. when first tap it, turn to class **"icon-red".**
2. Second tap it, turn to class **"icon-blue".**
3. third click - return to **"icon-white".**

and repeat.....

I found similar example here http://jsfiddle.net/7YATm/, but this example does not go back to default and it does not handling class name.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    var action = 1;

$("input").on("click", viewSomething);

function viewSomething() {
    if ( action == 1 ) {
        $("body").css("background", "honeydew");
        action = 2;
    } else if(action == 2) {
        $("body").css("background", "beige");
        action = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        $("body").css("background", "white");
        action = 1;
    }
  }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7YATm/43/)

**Edit**

```
  var action = 0;

$("input").on("click", viewSomething);
var colorArr=["honeydew","beige","white"];

function viewSomething() {
     $("body").css("background",colorArr[action%colorArr.length]);
    action++;

}
```

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7YATm/45/)

Comment: yup. this is what I want :)

Comment: overly verbose example. The *Reminder Operator* `%` looping trough an *Array*  is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="icon-white">click</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var classes = new Array("icon-white","icon-red","icon-blue");
var idx = 0;

$("a").on("click", changeClass);

function changeClass() {
    idx++;
    var nextClass = classes[idx % classes.length];
    $("a").attr("class",nextClass);
}
```

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/JmTLq/

**Explication:**

In the variable `classes` are all classes you want to show in the correct order. After clicking on the link, the `idx` variable counts up and the next class in the list will be updated for your link. This is executed in a loop because the `idx` variable allways counts up and with the `idx % classes.length` code, you will be sure that you chose allways an element in your array and you wont get an index out exception.

*(Sorry for my grammar and my english, corrections are welcome)*